# is it better to get few properties from a vertex or getting the whole vertex in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

which of these queries is cost effective when considering network calls and query process time

1)

```
g.V().has('personId','1234')
=> V[4232]
```

2)

```
g.V().has('personId','1234').values('name','age')
=> chris
=> 24
```

3)

```
g.V().has('personId','1234').valueMap('name','age')
    => [name:[chris],age:[24]]
```

4)

```
 g.V().has('personId','1234').properties('name','age')
        => vp[name->chris
         =>vp[age->24]
```

does getting the whole vertex cost us more of network bandwidth . i usually get vertices as the query processing is done quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cheapest will be options two and three. Returning an `Element`, which would be  a `Vertex`, `Edge`, `VertexProperty` will be more costly than returning an individual result or a `Map` or results. Even the following is less expensive than returning an entire `Element`:

```
g.V(1).valueMap(true)
```

which from a data perspective is basically the same as `g.V(1)`.

The basic rule ends up being not so different than SQL. You likely wouldn't do a `SELECT * FROM table`, nor should you return all the data from an element - only retrieve the data you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen,  although I felt the same but I had a doubt that would valueMap() step take more process time than the others to convert data into a map